# Python 3.6 web Sanic + uwsgi

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, uwsgi, sanic

i am trying to get my sanic webapp working with uwsgi and here is what i do:

Calling my uwsgi.ini file:

```
uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```

content:

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8001
wsgi-file = wsgi.py
asyncio  = 10
```

wsgi.py:

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

app.py:

```
import asyncio
import uvloop

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())

from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic(__name__)

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return json({"foo": "bar"})
```

When i request it, i get:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

i checked uwsgi and Sanic docs but could find any hint...could anybody help me with this issue? thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember sanic is not WSGI compliant yet [Make sanic WSGI compliant. #250](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/issues/250).

You can run it with gunicorn though, example:

```
gunicorn myapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker
```

You can also increase the sanic worker count to run on multiple CPU cores:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1337, workers=4)
```

Follow this guide: [Deploying](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/docs/sanic/deploying.md)